# JavaScript event handling scroll event with a delay

Tags: javascript, events

Can someone explaine and help me with this. My webpage is slugish because the scroll function is dragging it down. I need to add a delay but don't understand how to do this.

```
$(window).scroll(handleScroll);
```

Comment: Please update this question to show your own attempt, thanks.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You could write a simple [<s>throttle</s> debounce function](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2007/11/30/the-throttle-function/) to limit the times per second the scroll event will be handled.

```
function debounce(method, delay) {
    clearTimeout(method._tId);
    method._tId= setTimeout(function(){
        method();
    }, delay);
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    debounce(handleScroll, 100);
});
```

This will make sure there's at least 100ms between each call to `handleScroll` (or, in other words, it's called at most 10 times per second).

---

As zzzzBov pointed out, what Zakas describes as a throttle function is actually a debounce function. The difference is that debounce discards the superfluous scroll events, while a throttle function should queue them up to be handled later (but at a given maximum rate).

In the case of scroll events, you don't want real throttling.

Comment: That's actually [debouncing](http://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce), which is slightly different from throttling.

Comment: How can I use parameters in the function? For example I need something like debounce(handleScroll(parameter_1,parameter_2), 100)

Comment: @Garavani: you could wrap it in an inline function: `debounce(function () { handleScroll(parameter_1, parameter2) }, 100)`.

Comment: I believe debounce vs. throttle depends on the feature you want to implement on scroll. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65078485/5282202

Answer (score 9):

For scroll, you most likely need a throttle function like in Lodash or Underscore; great example:

```js
function throttle(func, timeFrame) {
  let lastTime = 0;
  return function () {
      const now = new Date();
      if (now - lastTime >= timeFrame) {
          func();
          lastTime = now;
      }
  };
}
```

This is a simple implementation from [this repository](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore#_throttle)

It depends on what you implement by scrolling callback. In some cases, the throttle will be much better to use. For example, infinite scrolling.

So **debounce** would trigger only when the user stops scrolling and we need to start fetching the content before the user reaches the bottom.

But with **throttle**, we can warranty that we are constantly checking how far we are from the bottom.

**Conclusion**:

- **debounce**: Grouping a sudden burst of events (like keystrokes) into a single one.
- **throttle**: Guaranteeing a constant flow of executions every X milliseconds. Like checking every 200ms of your scroll position to trigger a CSS animation.
- **requestAnimationFrame**: a throttle alternative. When your function recalculates and renders elements on the screen and you want to guarantee smooth changes or animations. Note: no IE9 support.