# React imported component is not working completely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I'm really new to React and I've been trying for some time now to make a scroll to top function. Using the existing tutorials and everything on google i've made this component :

```
Import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";


export default function ScrollToTop() {
const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false)

const toggleVisibility = () => {
    if(window.pageYOffset > 300) {
        setIsVisible(true);
    } else {
        setIsVisible(false);
    }
};

const ScrollToTop = () => {
    window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behavior: "smooth",
    });
};

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', toggleVisibility);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', toggleVisibility);
    };
}, []);

if (!isVisible) {
    return false
}

return (
<button className="button" onClick={ScrollToTop}>
    <div className="button__arrow button__arrow--up"></div>
</button>
)
};
```

the problem is that when i import it in the App.js it doesn't work properly, the scrolling part works perfectly, but the button it just stays at bottom of the page instead of appearing after a certain amount of scroll. This is the App.js:

```
return (
<div>
  {loading ? (
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
  ) : (
    <>
    <Navbar />
      <div className="Grid-container">
        {pokemonData.map((pokemon, i) => {
          return <Card key={i} pokemon={pokemon} />;
        })}
      </div>
    <ScrollToTop/>
    </>
  )}
</div>
);
}
```

Comment: This is a not a good idea. You're binding state updates to a scroll event, which will have really bad performance problems. You should [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12009497/4633197) the state updates.

Comment: Also, on the first render, the button will always appear because you're initializing the `isVisible` state as `false`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any overt issues in your `ScrollTop` implementation that would cause the scroll-to-top button to remain on the page even after scrolling back to the top, but I do see room for optimization.

1. For `onScroll` events it's best to use passive listeners.
2. Invoke `toggleVisibility` once immediately in the mounting `useEffect` to ensure proper initial state.
3. Apply Boolean Zen to the visibility toggler; Update the `isVisible` state with the result of the boolean comparison.
4. Just conditionally render the button in a single return.

Code:

```
function ScrollToTop() {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const toggleVisibility = () => {
    setIsVisible(window.pageYOffset > 300);
  };

  const ScrollToTop = () => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    toggleVisibility();

    window.addEventListener("scroll", toggleVisibility, { passive: true });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", toggleVisibility, { passive: true });
    };
  }, []);

  return isVisible ? (
    <button className="button" onClick={ScrollToTop}>
      <div className="button__arrow button__arrow--up">TOP</div>
    </button>
  ) : null;
}
```

[image: Edit react-imported-component-is-not-working-completely]

If you're still having issues with your implementation and usage try to create a codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live.